# Flavor-Topping-Size combinations

Tags: combinatorics

> An ice cream shop has 4 flavors of ice cream, 7 optional toppings, and three sizes. If a customer can select up to two flavors, how many distinct flavor-topping-size combinations are there?

I think the answer is $4^2 \cdot 2^7 \cdot 3$

The answer key says $72 \cdot 2^7$

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: I don't agree with either computation. As I see it:  there are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose two distinct flavors, and $4$ ways to choose a single flavor.  Hence there are $6+4=10$ possible choices for ice cream.  $2^7$ choices for toppings, and $3$ for size, makes the answer $10\times 2^7\times 3$.

Comment: You should explain your reasoning since that makes it easier for readers to detect any errors you may have made.

Comment: Why not $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^7 \cdot 3$? @lulu Am I including the non-distinct?

Comment: I gave my reasoning in my comment.  I don't understand where your expressions are coming from.

Comment: The answer $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^7 \cdot 3$ assumes that two flavors are selected and their order matters.  You have not accounted for the case that only one flavor is selected, nor have you indicated why you think the order in which the flavors of the ice cream are selected matters.

Comment: For yet another interpretation to throw into the mix... supposing the three sizes were in reference to one-scoop, two-scoop, or three-scoop size bowls, and we can't use partial scoops for flavors, we could have had a $4$ ways to have three scoops all of the same flavor, $4\cdot 3$ ways to have three scoops of two flavors with one appearing twice the other appearing once, $4$ ways to have two scoops of one flavor, $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to have two scoops of different flavors, and $4$ ways to have one scoop... for a total of $4+12+4+6+4=30$ different possible bowls before deciding toppings.

Comment: The end result is that the problem didn't do a very good job of explaining what does or doesn't count as a different outcome for the bowls, and so it is open to a bit of interpretation.  That said, I agree with lulu's interpretation the most.  Mine was just thrown in as a joke but to emphasize the ambiguity of the problem.  I see no interpretation that makes sense that gives an answer using $72=3\cdot 24$ in the calculation.

Comment: @lulu Although my answer disagrees with your comment, I (still) think that your comment's analysis is just as *plausible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the real challenge is how to reverse-engineer the problem composer's **mistaken** factor of $(24)$, for the number of ways of choosing the two flavors.

This is my **speculative explanation**. 
There are actually $(5)$ flavors, with the $5$th flavor representing (**void**).  So, you start with an enumeration of $(5)^2$, for the total number of ways of choosing two of the $(5)$ *flavors*, with replacement.

Here, it is presumed that the *order* of selection is relevant, in that vanilla on top of chocolate is presumed different than chocolate on top of vanilla.

Then, presumably, the problem composer deducted $(1)$ to get $(25 - 1 = 24)$, reasoning that you can **not** have both flavors be **void**.  This analysis **overlooks** the *effect of gravity*.  That is, having the first flavor be *void* and the second flavor be chocolate results in the same ice cream cone as having the first flavor be chocolate and the second flavor be void.

So, you have to deduct $(4)$ from the problem composer's enumeration, because the problem composer (for example) counted (void + vanilla) as distinct from (vanilla + void).

Here, my suggested enumeration of

$$(5)^2 - 1 - 4 = 20$$

for the number of flavors presumes that (for example) two scoops of vanilla is distinct from one scoop of vanilla.

---

The alternative way of arriving at the enumeration of $(20)$ would be to start with the assumption that there are exactly $(2)$ scoops, which yields $(4)^2$.  Then, you add $(4)$ for the number of ways of having only $(1)$ scoop.